# Is there a wordpress plugin for "news and activities" on personal website. See details

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am trying to have a 'news and activities' box (as shown [here](https://prakhar4.github.io/)) for my personal website. Can you point me to some plugin for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i wouldnt use a plugin for this .

just do this  write to text  editor

HTML

```
<div class="scroll-box">

<p>Your excerpt goes in here!</p>

</div>
```

and in your css

```
.scroll-box {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 400px; /* maximum height of the box, feel free to change this! */
    padding: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you want you can make your own shortcode so you dont have to wrap your text in html `<div class="scroll-box>`

Comment: On this website, https://prakhar4.github.io/, the 'news and activities' is a scrollable text-box. How do I reproduce it on wordpress main page?

Comment: add height like 200px to the div. and uss css property of overflow:scroll.